# Regular expression for date format dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: java

I'm Serching for regular expression for date format dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy but i did't found any where ?the regular expression should combination of both the date formats dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy.so please help me.

Comment: You didn't find the regex anywhere, huh?  Look at the long list of related questions on the right.

Comment: @devnull - this question has been asked several times on SOF itself :)

Comment: Look at the Related sidebar to this question.  Also look up some tutorials on regular expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try,

```
[0-9]{1,2}(/|-)[0-9]{1,2}(/|-)[0-9]{4}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.appropriate answer given along with proper explaination!

Comment: If it is for `dd-mm-yyyy` then it has a bug, because it's accepting `32-13-2021` :(